# iOS >> CoreData >> Should I Create an ID Attribute or Can I Use the SQLite Object ID?

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

When working with CoreData, do I need to create an ID attribute to have some sort of unique key for each record or can I access the data base ID field per each line in the table?

If there's a way to use the DB ID field, I would appreciate some direction about how to get to it when saving the record via the managedObject instance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSManagedObjects has a object id property. But when you create an ManagedObject there will be a temporary id, after storing the object into the DB it will get the permanent id. In my experience it is better to create your own id for each data. For example, if it is a simple table you can simply use timestamp as unique id or if it is a complex table with live and frequent update you should use some combination of fields in the table with the time stamp (you can convert the value to base64 to make it as a real id ;) ).

Answer (score 6):

Usually there is no need to create a id attribute because every object has an object ID (NSManagedObjectID). If you have a managed object you get it's id by sending -objectID to it. There is a catch though:

There is a catch: An NSManagedObjectID can be either temporary or permanent. When an object is created it has a temporary ID until you obtain a permanent ID for the object. When you persist an object Core Data automatically obtains a permanent ID for each object which still have temporary IDs.

If you need a custom ID attribute you should create it for each entity individually. Do not create an abstract entity with an ID attribute. If you do that Core Data will create a huge (monster) table for all entities that inherit from the abstract entity. This is bad.

Answer (score 3):

Apple advises against accessing SQLite files created by Core Data, because its format may change in the future. Following this rule, you should create your own IDs.

There's also an [NSManagedObject - objectID](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/objectID), but I'm not sure what's you use-case and whether you should use it.