# CoreData attribute id is needed

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am currently practicing with Swift and Core Data, making an app with a login. When i fetch data from my users entity i receive this:

```
[<NSManagedObject: 0x7f8f1300c640> (entity: Users; id: 0xd000000000380000 <x-coredata://E67F6A37-4E56-4A55-A01E-940D8BD9EBE9/Users/p14> ; data: {
password = password;
userName = user;})]
```

Is there a way to obtain de id 0xd000000000380000? I am new using core data and i have only used SQL. I know Core data is not a DB but i think that id is like a primary key, isn't it?

I want to obtain that to use it to find an object of an entity.

Im trying something like this:

```
data.objectID.uriRepresentation().absoluteString
```

But it givings me only, it's not what I want to get.

```
x-coredata://E67F6A37-4E56-4A55-A01E-940D8BD9EBE9/Users/p14
```

Comment: may be this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19245049/ios-coredata-should-i-create-an-id-attribute-or-can-i-use-the-sqlite-objec and ask proper qustions

Comment: Core Data is an ORM and you need to get SQL, primary keys and such stuff out of your head if you want to learn and understand Core Data properly. You want to think about objects rather than database records.

Comment: Do you have any example or something? Anyway it is possible to get this id?
I want this for a unique key in my code

Comment: Then use `objectID` as mentioned in the answer below. Otherwise, from your example it looks like `userName` would be suitable as an identifier.

Comment: Yeah I want to get any unique ID, but when im typing for example. print(username) this shows all records for me, not only one (if I selected one user from a list for example)

Answer (score 0):

Look at `objectID` property of your CoreData Entity.

But remember:

> If the receiver has not yet been saved, the object ID is a temporary
>   value that will change when the object is saved.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject/1506848-objectid?changes=_8